# Jquery does not display the value got from db

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got this data from my model:

```
{"message":"OK","reviews":[{"reviews":"5"}]}
```

and I want to display this data on the view using jquery. The problem is that it displays the message "ok" in this way

```
$(‘#show’).text(data.message);
```

but it does not displays the reviews "5" in this way

```
$(‘#display’).text(data.reviews[reviews]);
```

I got this error from console network "reviews is not defined ". Could you help me please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8bx5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below:

```
$(‘#display’).text(data.reviews[0].reviews);
```

Comment: it works now! Thank you very much! I will be able to accept the answer in 5min.